# How to send a "ping" event in SSE spring-web

Tags: java, spring-mvc, graphql, http2, server-sent-events

I'm trying to implement the graphql-sse specification in java, and to be able to do this I want to be able to send a heartbeat event. This can be done by sending the event: :\n\n to the event-stream.

However to be able to do this I can't send a ServerSentEvent object because it requires you to build a full object whereas this isn't a full object this is just an empty event. I also can't see any documentation on spring pinging the client to see if the connection is still open.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: You can emit a "ping" event like so: `ServerSentEvent.builder("").data(null).comment("").build()`

This will produce `:\n\n` in the text stream.

I had to read through the source code for the [ServerSentEventHttpMessageWriter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/codec/ServerSentEventHttpMessageWriter.java#L127-L152)

The code produces the event by using a comment which is prefixed with `:` so the client ignores it. And then because the comment is just an empty string it will add the `\n` afterwards and because there are no other fields set it will add another `\n` at the end. Note I only had to use builder("") to get my type working (for now anyway).

In kotlin you can use `ServerSentEvent.builder<String>().comment("").build()`